# Nginx: how to continuously cache response?

Tags: php, performance, nginx, load-balancing, nginx-config

I have a REST api on the backend and this api is cached by the Nginx (TTL is about 10m).

But I have a problem with number of calls to my backend api between moments when Nginx cache is expired and cache is established again.

This number of calls in such short period of time is too big and causes server overload.

How to continuously send cached response if [Nginx burst limit](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/) exceeds? (Docs: Excessive requests are delayed until their number exceeds the maximum burst size in which case the request is terminated with an [error](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_status))

[image]

Can I send previously cached response with Nginx while my backend is processing a new one? Is it possible to make custom trigger on burst limit event?

[image]

Any advice or example will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please check this - https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

Comment: One idea could be to have a cron in the background that's renewing the cache every 10m instead, and let all requests always fetch from the cache. If the cron has a hiccup, users would then get the previous cache instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks, may be it is better solution but I need to tune Nginx for now

Comment: @Dmitry thank you. Is it possible to send previously cached response to the clients instead of 503 error when burst limit exceeds? The idea is to continuously send cached response to the users but not to reject requests.

Answer (score 1):

As Igor (the guy behind Nginx) mentioned here:

> You may bypass cache using "Some-Secret-Header: 1" in a request and
> setting: proxy_no_cache $http_some_secret_header; The response may be
> cached.

(Source https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,99559,99567#msg-99567)

Another Alternative would be to use the "Cache Purge" module here https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/